# Imported sequence from Premiere Pro CS6 missing shots once in AE CS6

Tags: after-effects, premiere

I am importing a sequence from Premiere Pro into After Effects (by clicking on Import -> Premiere Pro), but there's a very annoying gap in A.E. where shots haven't been imported.

Here's the Premiere Pro Project - as you can see there are no gaps:

[image]

Here's the timeline in A.E. after import:

[image]

Note the huge gap between two files.

The files in this project are from different cameras, and it looks like some harmless .mov files are the ones missing in that gap.
I scrolled down thinking they might have been added as layers further down, but they are nowhere.
I have done this in the past in extremely similar ways, and never had this problem.